# Capturing packet which has NAT

Tags: tcpdump

How can I query the tcpdump command to check 3 way handshake for below mention packet assuming network interface as "any".

**1)**

```
Source IP address: 10.0.0.2
Destination IP address: 172.16.28.2
Source NAT: 172.16.28.3
Dport: 22
```

**2)**

```
Source IP address: 10.0.0.2
Destination IP address: 172.16.28.2
Source NAT: 172.16.28.3
Destination NAT: 172.16.28.4
Dport: 22
```